# Asp.Net Validation Control

Tags: asp.net

I Have Register Two Control In My Page .. There Is Some Of Validation In My Aspx Page And Validation In User Control . I Was Give Same Name Of Validation Group Same In User Control And Aspx Page Control. But I Post Page Then User Control Validation Not Working......
Is There Solution For That...

Comment: Can you post the code and the aspx markup? You will get much better answers if you show people exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Please be more specific, with small set of codes and examples or screenshots. So that you will have appropriate answer from the guru's.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the ValidationGroup property of the button to the same as the controls that should be validated?